# adding session data to page in rails breaks specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

When I add the following code into my header partial

```
<%= session[:user_id] %>
```

Everything works fine, but when I try to display a user's name from a session with the following...

```
<%= User.find(session[:user_id]).first_name %>
```

it breaks a lot of my `rspec` tests with the following error:

```
Failure/Error: <%= User.find(session[:user_id]).first_name %>

  ActionView::Template::Error:
    Couldn't find User with 'id'=
```

even though everything works just fine in the browser.

This is my user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  validates :first_name, :last_name, :address, :phone, :email, presence: true
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\w]+\.[a-z\d]+\z/
  validates :email, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                     uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password

  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    user = User.find_by(email: email)
    user && user.authenticate(password)
  end
end
```

and my session controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new 
  end

  def create 
    if user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id 
      flash[:notice] = "Welcome back, #{user.first_name}!"
      redirect_to user
    else 
      flash.now[:alert] = "Invalid email/password combination!"
      render :new
    end
  end

end
```

This is an example of a now-failing `rspec` test:

```
describe "deleting an item" do
  it "should remove item and redirect to index page" do
    item = Item.create(item_attributes)
    visit item_path(item)
    click_link 'Delete Item'
    expect(current_path).to eq(items_path)
    expect(page).not_to have_text(item.name)
    expect(page).to have_text("Item Successfully Deleted!")
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you see what does `<%= session[:user_id] %>` print?

Comment: its prints the actual user id of the user

Comment: What does `<%= session[:user_id] %>` print **in the rspec test**, where the error is actually happening? (Hint: it's `nil`.) (Can you give an example of a test that's failing? You're probably missing a `sign_in(user)` statement, in order to access session data.)

Comment: @TomLord, it gives no errors in the rspec test, but <%= User.find(session[:user_id]).first_name %> gives Failure/Error: <%= User.find(session[:user_id]).first_name %>

  ActionView::Template::Error:
    Couldn't find User with 'id'=

Comment: By "error", I meant "failing test". *When that test is running, what is `session[:user_id]`?* (Hint#2: it's `nil`.) (Can you give an example of a test that's failing? You're probably missing a `sign_in(user)` statement, in order to access session data.)

Comment: describe "deleting an item" do 

 it "should remove item and redirect to index page" do 
  item = Item.create(item_attributes)
  visit item_path(item)
  click_link 'Delete Item'
  expect(current_path).to eq(items_path)
  expect(page).not_to have_text(item.name)
  expect(page).to have_text("Item Successfully Deleted!")
 end
end

Comment: @TomLord, sorry, im new to this, not sure how to format that properly

Comment: You should always [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44144859/edit) to include any additional information like this. (I've done it for you just now.) As I guessed, in that test there is no user signing in. What behaviour do you expect to see if an anonymous user visits the `Items#show` page? (Should it force them to log in first, or just display the page without showing a name?) Write the test and controller+view accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Is the partial getting rendered in a page which can be accessed even without a logged in user.
Because in that case, the session[:user_id] will be nil, and you will get the mentioned error.

Also, devise defines a current_user for you, use that instead of doing a find. Also use other devise helper methods to check if a user is signed_in or not if you are using it in a page that can be accessed from anywhere.

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= current_user.first_name %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Session is not available in a view.

You should write some kind of current_user helper method that looks something like this in your application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :current_user
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
end
```

You can then call

```
<%= current_user.first_name %>
```

in your view. Try to keep any logic out of your views as it is generally considered bad practice.